# How can I overwrite a subimage of an opencv Mat?

Tags: c++, opencv

Is there any solution in opencv 2.4 which returns non-const reference to a sub-Mat?
I am asking this because I want to overwrite in place a subimage, defined by a roi,
but `mat(roi)` returns a const reference, so I can't write say `mat(roi)=mat2`,
or `cv::rectangle(mat(roi), rect_relative_to_roi)`.

EDIT: (I'll be more specific using Andrej's answer)

If I have defined complex drawing functions which work on a subimage,
is the only way I can avoid sending relative coordinates to the drawing function,
that I copy back and forth the subimage I want to work with?

I mean like this:

```
/* Mat canvas; */
Mat subimg = canvas(roi);
draw_sth(subimg);
subimg.copyTo(canvas(roi));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, it turns out

```
Mat subcanvas = canvas(roi);
draw_sth(subcanvas);
```

is the answer, it will modify the original canvas, as Mat's are to be looked at as reference-counted smart pointers, they just point at the image data.

On the other hand, copyTo() is not good. Take a look at the opencv code:

> ```
> //! copies the matrix content to "m".
> // It calls m.create(this->size(), this->type()).
> ```

Answer (score 6):

You can do

```
mat2.copyTo(mat(roi));
```